# HTTP or FileSystem Location?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

when create new WebSite or WebService in visual studio what is the difference between `filesystem` and `HTTP` location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[File system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5x4xz73%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

- Stores all of the files for the website inside a directory of your
  choosing.
- When debugging, Visual Studio runs the light-weight ASP.NET
  development server that is included in Visual Studio.
- This is the great when you want to run and debug website
  locally but do not want to run a local IIS.

**HTTP - [Local](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ckk1e6z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) , [Remote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h17hytcs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

- Used when you are working with a site deployed inside of IIS, either locally or remote server.
- The website might be configured at the root of the IIS webserver or in virtual directory, which is configured as an application.